# How to group and get three most frequent value?

Tags: python, pandas

i want to group by id and get three most frequent city. For example i have original dataframe

```
  ID    City
    1    London
    1    London
    1    New York
    1    London
    1    New York
    1    Berlin
    2    Shanghai
    2    Shanghai
```

and result i want is like this:

```
ID first_frequent_city   second_frequent_city   third_frequent_city
1   London               New York               Berlin
2   Shanghai             NaN                    NaN
```

Comment: Please show the code you attempted or at least something we can use to help you. You cannot just write what you want and expect the community to do all the work for you. At least add a code to define the panda dataframe

Comment: If you gave the input for your problem, life would be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for count values of `City` per `ID`, advantage is already values are sorted, then get counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), filter first `3` values by `loc`, pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), change columns names and last convert `ID` to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.groupby('ID')['City'].value_counts()
        .groupby(level=0).cumcount()
        .loc[lambda x: x < 3]
        .reset_index(name='c')
        .pivot('ID','c','City')
        .rename(columns={0:'first_', 1:'second_', 2:'third_'})
        .add_suffix('frequent_city')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   ID first_frequent_city second_frequent_city third_frequent_city
0   1              London             New York              Berlin
1   2            Shanghai                  NaN                 NaN
```

Comment: This isn't taking into account the fact that are only the three first cities. With a `head(3)` into the creation of `s`, it will work as desired. ;)

Comment: @MrNobody33 - thank you, added `.loc[lambda x: x < 3]` for filter first 3 values.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `count` as a reference to sort, then recreate dataframe by looping through `groupby` object:

```
df = (df.assign(count=df.groupby(["ID","City"])["City"].transform("count"))
        .drop_duplicates(["ID","City"])
        .sort_values(["ID","count"], ascending=False))
    
print (pd.DataFrame([i["City"].unique()[:3] for _, i in df.groupby("ID")]).fillna(np.NaN))

          0         1       2
0    London  New York  Berlin
1  Shanghai       NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit long, essentially you groupby twice, first part works on the idea that grouping sorts the data in ascending order, the second part allows us to split the data into individual columns :

```
(df
.groupby("ID")
.tail(3)
.drop_duplicates()
.groupby("ID")
.agg(",".join)
.City.str.split(",", expand=True)
.set_axis(["first_frequent_city",
           "second_frequent_city", 
           third_frequent_city"],
           axis="columns",)
)


     first_frequent_city    second_frequent_city    third_frequent_city
ID          
1      London                 New York                Berlin
2      Shanghai               None                    None
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the `.count` by `ID` and `City` and then use `np.where()` with `.groupby()` with `max`, `median` and `min`. Then set the index and unstack rows to columns on the `max` column.

```
df = df.assign(count=df.groupby(['ID', 'City'])['City'].transform('count')).drop_duplicates()
df['max'] = np.where((df['count'] == df.groupby('ID')['count'].transform('min')), 'third_frequent_city', np.nan)
df['max'] = np.where((df['count'] == df.groupby('ID')['count'].transform('median')), 'second_frequent_city', df['max'])
df['max'] = np.where((df['count'] == df.groupby('ID')['count'].transform('max')), 'first_frequent_city', df['max'])
df = df.drop('count',axis=1).set_index(['ID', 'max']).unstack(1)
```

output:

```
    City
max first_frequent_city second_frequent_city    third_frequent_city
ID          
1   London              New York                Berlin
2   Shanghai            NaN                     NaN
```