# Pandas: How to get lists of 5 most frequent value in column for each hour of the day?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some pandas data.

| Date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-06 12.00 | 18.5 | 0 |
| 2021-05-06 13.00 | 20.3 | 9.7% |
| 2021-05-06 14.00 | 16.1 | -20.7% |
| 2022-05-06 10.00 | 50.4 | 4.0% |
| 2022-05-06 11.00 | 52.4 | 3.9% |

How to get lists of 5 most frequent value  in column B for each hour of the day?

For example:

| hour | most common value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00 | +3%, 7%, -9%, 0.5%, 18% |
| 12.00 | +6%, -3%, 4% |
| 13.00 | 1, 4% |
| 19.00 | 2%,-5% |
| 23.00 | 11%, -4% |

Comment: the data is insufficient. It seems your data is already hourly. Why not group by that then use `nlargest?

Comment: `df.groupby('Date')['B'].nlargest(5)`?

Comment: @onyambu It's don't work, show all most frequent unsort value, but with hour label.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Date": "2021-05-06 10.00", "A": 18.5, "B": "9.7%"},
        {"Date": "2021-05-06 10.00", "A": 20.3, "B": "9.7%"},
        {"Date": "2021-05-06 14.00", "A": 16.1, "B": "-20.7%"},
        {"Date": "2022-05-06 10.00", "A": 50.4, "B": "4.0%"},
        {"Date": "2022-05-06 11.00", "A": 52.4, "B": "3.9%"},
    ]
)
df

#               Date    A       B
#0  2021-05-06 10.00    18.5    9.7%
#1  2021-05-06 10.00    20.3    9.7%
#2  2021-05-06 14.00    16.1    -20.7%
#3  2022-05-06 10.00    50.4    4.0%
#4  2022-05-06 11.00    52.4    3.9%
```

You can do this:

```
# Convert to correct pandas time format
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],  format="%Y-%m-%d %H.%M")

# Apply transformations
x = (df.groupby([df.Date.dt.hour])["B"].value_counts()
       .loc[lambda x: x<5]
       .reset_index(name="c")
       .pivot(index="Date", columns="c", values="B"))

# Create column
x["most_freq"] = x.apply(
    lambda x: ", ".join([y for y in x.astype(str) if y != "nan"]), axis=1
)

result = x[['most_freq']].rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
```

This is `result`:

```
    Date    most_freq
0   10      4.0%, 9.7%
1   11      3.9%
2   14      -20.7%
```

Comment: inspired by @jezrael and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63351782/4713169) question of his

Comment: ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-22-6e196304b1ca> in <module>  
      3        .loc[lambda x: x<5]  
      4        .reset_index(name="c")  
----> 5        .pivot(index="Date", columns="c", values="B"))                                               
      6   
      7 # Create column   
        ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @andru that's odd. Make sure to have the same column names as my sample data. If you don't, please update your question with the correct column names.

Comment: The same columns name and types Date A B
21198 2022-05-19 19:00:00 967.40 -0.8%
21199 2022-05-19 20:00:00 270.19 1.0%

Comment: 965311532 It's not work, first 'x<5' get only 5 rows for every hours.... and second pivot rise error when same value in different hour... But you helped me to find solution... Thanks.. You save my time.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers, didn't work, but helped me to find solution:

```
x = (df.groupby([df.Date.dt.hour])["B"].value_counts()  
   .loc[lambda x: x<1000]  
   .reset_index(name="c"))  

for j in range(0,24):  
   print(x.loc[x['Date']==j][:5])
```

The solution is not perfect. Where x<1000 is max row for every hour, that's enough for my data. As a result, I received 24 pandas series of 5 most frequent value for each hour of the day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).